# request.POST pylons, getting array like in php

Tags: php, python, pylons

I have a dynamic form, i must bulid some post array to field witch some id.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="field[124][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="field[124][]" value="2">
```

In php i can simply get value and key.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
if(is_array($value){
  foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
  //i get key=>124 and all values for this key
   }
}
}

<input type="checkbox" name="field" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="field" value="2">
```

In pylons for array of checkbox i can use

```
request.POST[field].getall()
```

How can i create in pylons post array like in PHP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .getall() of multidict object, for example:

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="field[124][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="field[124][]" value="2">
```

controller:

```
values = request.POST.getall('field[124][]')
# >>> values
# [u'1', u'2']
```

---

another way to get this list is by using .dict_of_lists(), example:

controller:

```
d = request.POST.dict_of_lists()
values = d['field[124][]']
# >>> d
# {'field[124][]':[u'1', u'2']}
# >>> values
# [u'1', u'2']
```